# jQuery span text copy and use as width

Tags: jquery, copy, width

I am trying to copy a span text value to a html width value but i cant get it working?

With the code below i manged to duplicate the text but how can i set it as the width of the p element?

```js
$('.duplicate').text(function() {
  return $(this).closest('ul li').find('em').text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <p class="duplicate"></p>
    <em>100</em>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="duplicate"></p>
    <em>200</em>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="duplicate"></p>
    <em>300</em>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the function to return the value to `width()`, not `text()`:

```js
$('.duplicate').width(function() {
  return $(this).closest('ul li').find('em').text();
});
```

```css
p.duplicate {
  min-height: 10px; /* just for testing */
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <p class="duplicate"></p>
    <em>100</em>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="duplicate"></p>
    <em>200</em>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="duplicate"></p>
    <em>300</em>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Strange i did change that and tested with that but that wasnt working for me... but i see now that it is working! Thank you namefellow ;-)